# Question about Fourier transform of $e^{-\pi x^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, fourier-transform

Let $\varphi (x) = e^{-\pi x^2}$ and let $F:=\tilde {\varphi}(\xi)$, the Fourier transform of $\varphi $. I must show that $F$ is a solution of these equations: $$F'(\xi)=-2\pi \xi F(\xi)$$ $$F (0)=1.$$ Now, $F(\xi)=\int e^{-\pi x^2-2\pi i x \xi}dx$, so we have the following:$F'(\xi)=\tilde {(-2\pi i x \varphi(x))}=\int e^{-\pi x^2-2\pi i x \xi}(-2\pi i x)dx$.

I am stuck here; probably I must do a proper substitution, however I tried a few and they didn't work. Can you give me a hint? Thanks

Comment: @Thorgott why it should be like that? If I derive $F (\xi) $ (respect to $\xi $) I obtain $\int e^{-\pi x^2-2\pi i x\xi} (-2\pi i x)dx$

Comment: You may find it productive to complete the square in the exponent of your Fourier transform.

Comment: @Dorian Sorry, it was early in the morning and it seems I wasn't fully awake then. Your expression is correct. Note that $\varphi^{\prime}(x)=-2\pi x\varphi(x)$, so $F^{\prime}(\xi)=i(\hat{-2\pi x\varphi(x)})=i\hat{\varphi^{\prime}(x)}=...$-

Comment: Thanks @Thorgott, however the only thing that I would use to complete the identity is again what I wrote above; what should I  put on the dots instead?

Comment: @Semiclassical I tried that too, but after completing the square I didn't know how to continue: the Gaussian integral is taken on the real line, while here I have $e^{-\pi(x+i\xi )^2}$

Comment: If you write down the Fourier transform of $\varphi^{\prime}$, you can perform integration by parts and continue. To compute the integral of $e^{-\pi(x+i\xi)^2}$, integrate $e^{-\pi z^2}$ along the rectangular contour with corners $-R,R,R+i\xi,-R+i\xi$ and take the limit as $R\rightarrow\infty$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that, in general, your function $\varphi$ solves $$\left(\frac{d}{dx}+2\pi x\right)\varphi=0.$$ If you take the Fourier transform of this equation and use how the Fourier transform intertwines differentiation and multiplication (although it's extra easy for this particular function), you get $$i\left(2\pi \xi+2\pi \frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{d}{d\xi}\right)\hat{\varphi}=0.$$ So, $$\hat{\varphi}(\xi)=\hat{\varphi}(0) e^{-\pi \xi^2},$$ and $$\hat{\varphi}(0)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\pi x^2}e^{-2\pi i x\cdot 0}\, dx=1,$$ which is a standard computation. So, $\hat{\varphi}(\xi)=e^{-\pi \xi^2}.$

Comment: I think I find why my result is different because of the fourier transform of a derivative that depends on the definition. +1 for your answer

Answer (score 1):

$$\varphi (x) = e^{-\pi x^2}$$
Differentiate:
$$\varphi' (x) = e^{-\pi x^2}(-2\pi x)$$
$$\varphi' (x) = \varphi (x)(-2\pi x)$$
Fourier transform
$$2\pi ik\hat {\varphi} (k) = -i\hat{\varphi}' (k)$$
$$ \hat{\varphi}' (k)=- {2\pi} k \hat {\varphi} (k) $$
This DE can easily be solved as it's separable:
$$\frac {  \hat{\varphi}(k)'}{\hat {\varphi} (k)}=-{2\pi} k $$

It's separable:
$$(\ln  \hat{\varphi} (k))'=-{2\pi} k$$
Integrate:
$$ \hat{\varphi} (k)=Ce^{- {k^2}{\pi}} $$
$$C=\hat{\varphi} (0)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\pi x^2} dx=I$$
Substitute $u=\sqrt {\pi}x \implies du=\sqrt {\pi}dx$:
$$\implies I=\frac 1 {\sqrt {\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-u^2} du=1$$
$$ \hat{\varphi} (k)=e^{- {k^2}{\pi}} \text{ , and :}  \hat{\varphi} (0)=1 $$